# OXID eShop - Autocompletion in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, oxid

I want to use Eclipse Kepler to handle my OXID eShop project.

Until now i can't figure out how to setup my php-project so that the oxid classes are used for auto.completion/suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some tries i figured it out

1. disabled "automatic build"
2. clean project
3. add "application" to include path
4. enable "automatic build"
5. let the project build
6. enjoy autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, there is a module for that:
https://github.com/DSB/Oxid-Module-IDE-Helper

I tried this before, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can't , because the oxid parent class is yourclass_parent

If you want to see in eclipse you need to add in modules/function.php line for each class that you create:

Class yourclass_parent expand ox_oxid_class